# Declaring a long constant byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, constants

I have a long byte array that I need to declare in my C# code. I do something like this:

```
public static class Definitions
{
    public const byte[] gLongByteArray = new byte[] { 
        1, 2, 3,
        //and so on
    };
}
```

But I get an error that the const array may be initialized only with nulls.

If I change `const` to `static` it compiles, but the question I have is this -- when I declare it as `public static byte[] gLongByteArray` it won't be initialized every time my app loads, right? In that case the `gLongByteArray` variable will simply point to an array that is defined in the compiled exe/dll file that loads into memory. The reason I'm asking is because this array is pretty long and I don't want my program to waste CPU cycles on loading it every time the app starts, or worse, this class is referenced...

Comment: The performance implications are minimal, even if you could do this.  The bigger issue is that a `byte[]` is not a very good candidate for being a constant.  It's advised to use constants for things that should never change, but a sequence of bytes (especially a long sequence of bytes) may well change in a future implementation.  Using 'const' causes the compiler to 'bake-in' all references to the constant, which means that the constant value is _duplicated_ throughout your code.  If you later change the constant, only those modules compiled against the new constant will have the new value.

Comment: As others have said, don't make performance decisions on the basis of guesses; make them on the basis of fact. Create a realistic sized array and *measure your startup performance* with and without it. Then you'll know whether it has an effect or not. Large byte arrays initialized by constants are handled reasonably efficiently.

Comment: @EricLippert: There's no guessing involved -- ever heard of a debugger?

Comment: @ahmd0: I *have* heard of a debugger; debuggers are for *finding and removing bugs*, hence the name. The tool you want is a *profiler*, not a *debugger*. Profilers determine timing data and assign it to code. In fact, you should *never* try to derive performance data while running a debugger. The runtime knows that a debugger is attached and *deliberately makes your program run less efficiently* so that it can be more easily debugged. Remember, your *customers* are not going to run the program in the debugger, so if you want to know their experience, you shouldn't either.

Comment: @EricLippert: My reference to a debugger was not to profile the application but to see disassembled code that could be _wasted_ for initialization.

Comment: @ahmd0: Read my comment again. **If the debugger is attached then the code generated is often less efficient than it would be if the debugger is not attached.** If you want to look at the actual generated code in the debugger then what you have to do is *attach* to the *release* version of the program *after the code you want to examine has already been jitted*.  If you don't do that then again, *you're not necessarily seeing the same code that your customer is running*.

Comment: But more generally: I am not able to look at generated code and tell you how fast it runs. If this is a super power that you have, that's great, but most people do not have that super power. Instead of developing that super power, I just use a profiler.

Comment: @EricLippert: I don't know why I reply to this. It's just a waste of time. I'll explain it briefly to avoid your snarky comments though. If the initialization of a large array (by loading it into RAM from an EXE file image) is present  -- this will qualify as a _waste_ of CPU cycles because the compiler can simply refer to it in the loaded file image. I obviously can't tell how fast it runs as you assumed.

Comment: @ahmd0: It is often my experience that people see in others what they do themselves. You make a sarcastic rhetorical question like "Ever heard of a debugger?" and then assume that my reply is equally sarcastic. It's not. I'm giving you excellent advice, for free. I'm sorry to hear that it's not appreciated.

Comment: Also, you seem to be mixing up the compiler and the runtime.

Comment: Sometimes I just wish that SO allowed downvoting comments.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

*Compile-time constants* (those declared with the `const` keyword) are severely restricted. No code must be executed to get such a constant, or otherwise it could not be a compile-time constant. `const` constants are `static` by default.

If you want to create a constant and you cannot use a compile-time constant, you can use `static readonly` instead:

```
public static readonly byte[] longByteArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

The `static` keyword ensures it is initialized only once, and part of the declaring type (and not each instance). The `readonly` keyword ensures the `longByteArray` *variable* cannot be changed afterwards.

```
Definitions.longByteArray = new byte[] { 4, 5, 6 };   // Not possible.
```

**Warning**: An array is mutable, so in the above code I *can* still do this:

```
Definitions.longByteArray[3] = 82;                    // Allowed.
```

To prevent that, make the type not an array but a read-only collection interface, such as [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) or [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx), or even better a read-only collection type such as [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) which doesn't even allow modification through casting.

```
public static readonly IReadOnlyList<byte> longByteArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: Fine answer, but you sample will not compile as `byte a = 82974;` is compile time error.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good catch. I just had to came up with some random digits. :P

Comment: In the last example with the IReadOnlyLIst, I you can still cast it to a byte[] and modify values in the array. As you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/jcmcbeth/00aee115b6ec18de617729e4e40af655). If that was a list you could use AsReadonly() on the end.

Comment: @jcmcbeth If it hurts, don't do it. If you explicitly cast your way around the interface, you're essentially stating that you know what you are doing and accept the consequences. I can change the underlying implementation in a future version and your cast will fail.

Comment: @Virtlink With that logic might as well not make it readonly at all, if you are modifying it you know what you are doing and accept the consequences.

Comment: @jcmcbeth I don't agree about not making it read-only. The type specifies what the programmer expects you to do with the object: it's a contract. By not making it read-only the programmer is allowing too much; the contract is too broad. Casting is one way for you to intentially violate a read-only contract, which you do at your own risk. In fact, if I follow your line of reasoning not even a read-only class such as [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) would suffice, because you could still intentionally circumvent the protections through reflection.

Comment: @Virtlink I agree, casting the read only list to a byte[] array to circumvent a read only contract is almost as bad as using reflection to do so. Fortunately you can prevent this by using a list combined with the AsReadOnly() extension or use the byte[] array with Array.AsReadOnly().

Answer (score 6):

You can't make a `const` array. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx):

> User-defined types, including classes, structs, and arrays, cannot be **`const`**.

You'd have to declare it as a static readonly field like this

```
public static class Definitions
{
    public static readonly byte[] gLongByteArray = new byte[] { 
        1, 2, 3,
        //and so on
    };
}
```

Of course, there's nothing to stop someone from overwritting your array elements at run-time, like this:

```
Definitions.gLongByteArray[0] = 0xFF;
```

You'd have to use one of the built in collections that *@Virtlink* suggests or create your own custom readonly array class to prevent that ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953327/1715579)).

Answer (score 2):

Write all content to a file and embed as resource!

Answer (score 0):

static classes will be initialized when you first load the application. Don't worry about the performance unless you've specifically measured that it's a problem.

Comment: Technically, static initialization occurs at a variable time, depending on how/when the class is referenced.  This is rarely an issue, but it's worth knowing.  It's guaranteed to have been run at least by the time you reference the field.