# How to create a Byte Array Constant in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to use AES algorithm in my project so i thought of having a constant Key for all the data to encrypt.how to create a global constant byte array in C# which is available as key ?

Comment: You cannot. C# only allows `const` on `string` and `numerical` types. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx You should use `static readonly` instead.

Comment: @Aron you can have `const` on reference type, but you wan't be able to assign anything but `null` to it.

Comment: The idea of a hard coded constant key is concerning for encryption purposes. It'd be better to derive the key from user input - like a password - using PBKDF2 or similar.

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with? Writing a C# program? Creating a byte array? What do you mean by “constant Key”? You mean declaring it `const` or you want to pass it to another method and ensure that method doesn't change it?

Comment: beware of decompile on your program, your key will be expose by anyone

Comment: This is probably exactly what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501289/c-sharp-byte-encryption

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring a long constant byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560007/declaring-a-long-constant-byte-array)

Comment: +1 because this is the number one result from google on this topic - although the detail question itself is stated very foggy :-) ... and one of the answers below is really useful (at least for me)

Answer (score 5):

The only `byte[]` constant you can create is following one:

```
const byte[] myBytes = null;
```

That's because `byte[]` (or every array in general) is a reference type, and reference type constants can only have `null` value assigned to it (with the exception of `string` type, which can be used with string literals).

> Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
static readonly byte[] key = new byte[] { .. }
```

Or maybe consider using a string, and then converting it to bytes using `Bin64`

Note that the array is read/write and thus not constant.

**Edit**

A better way is to store a constant string in Bin64 and convert back to `byte[]` on the fly.

```
class Program
{
    const string key = "6Z8FgpPBeXg=";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(key);

    }
}
```