# Why infer doesn't work when declaring array as constant

Tags: vb.net, constants

This codes fail

```
Const BASEARRAY = {"BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "USDT", "PAX", "USDC", "XRP", "USDS", "TRX", "TRY", "BUSD", "NGN", "RUB", "EUR"}
```

Changing CONST to private shared also don't work.

```
   Private Shared BASEARRAY As String() = {"BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "USDT", "PAX", "USDC", "XRP", "USDS", "TRX", "TRY", "BUSD", "NGN", "RUB", "EUR"}
```

works though.

```
   Private Shared BASEARRAY = {"BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "USDT", "PAX", "USDC", "XRP", "USDS", "TRX", "TRY", "BUSD", "NGN", "RUB", "EUR"}
```

I just need to add as String() and change const to private shared.

But why does it fail? I want a constant array as my constant. I don't intent to change it. It seems that const is the right keyword. Why fails? And why doesn't infer works. Why do I have to add as string()

Comment: What is constant about an array?  `I don't intent to change it.` - Do you really expect a compiler to infer your usage intents and ignore its predefined usage rules for a keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Constants aren't allowed to be of a generic type, or as an array type. Here's some [documentation on that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/constants-must-be-of-an-intrinsic-or-enumerated-type).

By stating...

```
Const BASEARRAY = {"BTC", "ETH", ...}
```

You're trying to instantiate an array of `Object` types as a constant, which isn't allowed.

So, to answer your question, **that's just how it's designed.**

If you have no intentions of changing your `BASEARRAY` variable, simply set it as `ReadOnly`, which is [designed for situations like these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/readonly).

If leaving the type out of it (as in, you leave out `As String()`) gives you an error, it's because you probably have `Option Strict On`. Here's some [documentation for that error specifically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/configuring-warnings-in-visual-basic?view=vs-2019#declarations-require-as-clause-warnings), and here's some [stuff on Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Not declaring a type makes the type implicit, which `Option Strict On` (without `Option Infer On`) disallows. Leaving Option Strict on, you can say...

```
Private Shared ReadOnly BASEARRAY As String() = {"BTC", "ETH", "BNB"}
```

Beware, however. Making this `ReadOnly` prevents it from having another array assigned to it, but it *does* permit manipulation of one or more of its array members.

If that level of protection isn't enough for you, look into [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953327/11171084) about truly read-only arrays.

Comment: I have option infer on